# Unreal Engine Code Signing Error: no signing certificate "iOS Development" found

Tags: ios, package, unreal-engine4, ios-provisioning, ios-app-signing

I'm having issues with app signing. Here's my steps:

**1.** I created an unreal engine project on my **windows** laptop

**2.** On my **windows** laptop I followed the instructions here to create a **distribution** signing certificate, App ID, and provisioning profile. https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Mobile/iOS/Provisioning/index.html

**3.** I tried to Package Project for iOS on my **windows** laptop and got this error:

```
Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "provisionProfileName" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the get-task-allow entitlement.

Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK iOS 12.1
```

**4.** I copied the file to my **macbook** and tried to Package Project for iOS there. I got this error:

```
Code Signing Error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS" signing certificate matching team ID "teamID" with a private key was found.
```

In both cases I had a Distribution Provision Profile and Certificate imported to Unreal Engine under Project Settings->Platforms->iOS. My bundle identifier is a wildcard.

On the macbook under Project Settings->Platforms->iOS->Build I checked on Automatic Signing and entered my Team ID under IOS Team ID

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: Hi Thariff, It was a long time ago so I don’t remember but I found this in my personal notes: “Remaking certificate and making sure it matches on the iOS App Store got me past this error”

First decide, development or distribution. Then make sure everything matches that type: The provision profile, certificate, and Unreal Engine settings. There's a checkbox "For Distribution"

You might find some information here helpful. In this case I was building on my macbook for distribution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421184/error-itms-90161-invalid-provisioning-profile/59060177#59060177

Comment: After I got past this issue I had another one where Unreal Engine was pointing to an old provision profile. If it refuses to pick the correct one you can delete the old ones manually.
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/223227/remove-obsolete-mobileprovision-profiles-ios.html?childToView=223233#answer-223233. Be careful with Automatic Signing checkbox in Unreal Engine. I had to turn automatic signing off and For Distribution on to make sure it picked the Distribution certificate.